# GDB: Setting a convenience variable using an environment variable

Tags: gdb, environment-variables

I would like to do use a variable from my bash/ gdb environment and set it as a convenience variable in gdb.

```
(gdb) show environment

bar=1

(gdb) set $foo = (show environment bar)

(gdb) show convenience

foo=1
```

Of course, my second (gdb) command returns an error. I have looked quite a bit to see if something like this is possible. But perhaps I am looking in the wrong direction. Could anyone be of help?

Comment: Environment values are character strings. Convenience variables can be various types.  Do you want $foo to be `1` or `"1" ` ?

Comment: I presume it is of string type. I am specifically looking to use the local rank of a process to decide the value of $foo

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using builtin Python, like so:

```
(gdb) py import os
(gdb) py gdb.set_convenience_variable("home", os.environ["HOME"])
(gdb) p $home
$1 = "/home/me"
```